# How could you rebuild Java code and still have access to a data structure in a previous build?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, memory

So let's say we have a huge text file with 100 million numbers that takes 10 minutes to process and store into an ArrayList. Using eclipse, how would I store this list into memory so I don't have to take 10 minutes to process the text file every time I test code.

I have tried writing the list to a file and doing this:

```
    //store the contents of the text file as a list object in C:/filepath
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/filepath");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = (ArrayList<Integer>)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    //process newList
```

But this is very inefficient presumably because the file isn't stored into memory.

Is there a trick to be able to do this efficiently and only having to process the text file once and still use the fruits of that processing time in many different builds?

Comment: There are a number of methods to persist data. If some text takes "10 minutes to load", perhaps it is better stored in a database and queried appropriately? Or perhaps it just needs to be streamed? Or pre-processed? Or perhaps the results can be cached? Or it is time for a [good] SSD upgrade :}

Comment: This is not a sane size for test input.

Answer (score 5):

No. And that file is not read at build-time. It reads the file at run-time. And it must re-read the file every time the program (re-)starts.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's now how memory management works. Once your Java program loads the file into memory, you will have considerably faster access to it. But once it dies, that memory will be lost with the termination of the JVM. There's no way to reclaim. The only way to get it back is to re-create it in another JVM instance.

Alternatively, for testing purposes, you can modify your program to never end. But there's no way to persist memory from a closed JVM.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your test data is unnecessarily large, unless your test is to process a large file, in which case you shouldn't be trying to optimise it. It would be better to use a test file that provides just enough variety to cover your various test cases.

You don't say how you test your code, but your essentially asking whether you can hot deploy your changes to a running jvm. I've not used it, but there are commercial products that can assist with that, although they may not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things

- compress the data using gzipoutputstream if you're not on SSD and your file IO is slower than your CPU
- if you don't need to access the whole file everybuild have you considered putting it up as a service that allows you to pick the number you want from the array when needed.
- make sure you use buffered streams to allow reading in batches.